# Fallo arranque local sprint boot con javax.validation

Tags: java, spring-boot, servidor

Estoy tratando de arrancar un servidor local  de una aplicación herededa de ex-compañeros de trabaja que se utiliza Java y Spring Boot y en la consola estoy viendo lo siguiente:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-03-08 10:35:43.985 ERROR 40236 --- [utor-thread-232] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean.configureParameterNameProvider(LocalValidatorFactoryBean.java:315)

The following method did not exist:

    javax.validation.Configuration.getDefaultParameterNameProvider()Ljavax/validation/ParameterNameProvider;

The method's class, javax.validation.Configuration, is available from the following locations:

    bundleresource://78.fwk1928791586/javax/validation/Configuration.class
    wsjar:file:/C:/OpenDevECI/Maven/repository/javax/validation/validation-api/2.0.1.Final/validation-api-2.0.1.Final.jar!/javax/validation/Configuration.class
    wsjar:file:/C:/OpenDevECI/Maven/repository/jakarta/validation/jakarta.validation-api/2.0.2/jakarta.validation-api-2.0.2.jar!/javax/validation/Configuration.class

The class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

    javax.validation.Configuration: file:/C:/OpenDevECI/wlp-webProfile8/dev/api/spec/com.ibm.websphere.javaee.validation.1.0_1.0.32.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of javax.validation.Configuration
```

En el fichero pom.xml tengo lo siguiente (Lo pongo entero por si puede ayudaros, es posible que se me escape algún detalle):

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<artifactId>opseguroseciws-WEB</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<parent>
    <groupId>es.elcorteingles</groupId>
    <artifactId>opseguroseciws</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</parent>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <spring.boot.version>2.3.2.RELEASE</spring.boot.version>
</properties>

<build>
    <finalName>opseguroseciws</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>opseguroseciws-CICS</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>inspireautomation-client</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>es.eci.servicios.CKA20002</groupId>
        <artifactId>CKA20002-Jade</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>es.eci.servicios.CKA20007</groupId>
        <artifactId>CKA20007-TablasMaestras</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>es.eci.servicios.CKA20009</groupId>
        <artifactId>CKA20009-AccesoCics</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>es.elcorteingles</groupId>
        <artifactId>seguroseci-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.12</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
        <artifactId>monitoring-interceptors</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.5.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator-annotation-processor</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.5.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>axis</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
        <!-- <scope>provided</scope> -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.1</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

He mirado la configuraciones, sobretodo javax y jakarta que es lo que más me mosquea, y por lo que he visto no he encontrado nada raro.

¿Podéis ayudarme? Cualquier duda o aclaración, por favor, decídmelo y lo reviso.

Muchas gracias anticipadas.

Un saludo.

Comment: Puedes agregar todo el POM, para evaluar todas tus dependencias.

Comment: Edito la publicación añadiendo el POM entero

Comment: Revisando el POM de spring boot 2.3.2 `https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-dependencies/2.3.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-dependencies-2.3.2.RELEASE.pom` ya actualizo jakarta entonces tienes que quitar `javax.validation` yo creo que tienes dependencias mezcladas porque spring boot web ya incluye la validacion, si agregar la salida del comando `mvn dependency:tree` puedes ver cuales estarían de más.

Comment: Prueba quitar ` <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>` creo que con eso al menos te quitas el problema para iniciar el proyecto.

Comment: He quitado esa dependencia y sigue fallando

Comment: Agrega la salida del comando `mvn dependency:tree`